# Show loaded images on page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Here is my markup to show my loaded images:

```
<div id="loadedImages" style="display: inline-block;">
  <img alt="First image" src="" />
  <img alt="Second image" src="" /> 
</div>
```

In servlet i loaded images like

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> multiparts = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);

ImageHolder.setImage1(ImageIO.read(multiparts.get(0).getInputStream()));
ImageHolder.setImage2(ImageIO.read(multiparts.get(1).getInputStream()));
```

ImageHolder is a simple class which contains two static fields `BufferedImage` and getters/setters.

How to show this images on page and what should be in `src`?

Comment: You may want to show your current file structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `Servlet` that will load the image and send that to the output stream. You can also use a request parameter to specify the image you want to load:

```
<div id="loadedImages" style="display: inline-block;">
  <c:url var="firstURL"
    value="/ImageServlet?imageId=First.jpg" />
  <img alt="First image" src="${firstURL}" />

  <c:url var="secondURL"
    value="/ImageServlet?imageId=Second.jpg" />
  <img alt="Second image" src="${secondURL}" /> 
</div>
```

And define a `Servlet` as below to load and send images to the client:

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String imageName = request.getParameter("imageId");
     //Read image into byte array
     byte[] data = ImageHolder.readImage(imageName);
     //Write image into output stream
     response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
     response.getOutputStream().write(data);
     }

}
```